# wolframscript output differs when code is stored in a file

Tags: scripting

I noticed that the output from `wolframscript` appears to be different when running interactively and when running with code in a file.

I tried searching for this, but it's a bit hard to describe, so I didn't find anything.

Here is an example of the interactive output, which looks normal to me.

```
$ wolframscript 
Wolfram Language 12.1.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2020 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= Print[N[1/7,50]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714
```

Here is the output when the code is in a file

```
$ echo 'Print[N[1/7,50]]' > code && wolframscript -file code
0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285`50.
```

I don't understand where the suffix `` 285714285714285714285714285`50. `` comes from and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Print keeps the `NumberMarks`. Change your code to disable them:

```
Print[ToString[N[1/7, 50], NumberMarks -> False]]
(* result: 0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714 *)
```

Comment: It seems that `ToString` by itself is sufficient, but thanks for mentioning that the extra substring was a number mark, because I didn't know what to call it.